# Regular Expression Differences Between ls and find to search for 1 string or another string

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I'm having a minor brain-fart that I'm sure someone can answer quickly.  I'm using cygwin to get a bash shell in windows (in case that has any idiosyncrasies) and am having trouble shifting a regular expression between ls and find.

I have a bunch of files that I need to access, some which start EA_ and some which start FS_ so I can list them with ls like this

```
ls -l {EA,FS}_*
```

and this also works fine with wc but when I try to use this in a find, the regex doesn't seem to be right:-

```
find . -iname "{EA,FS}_*"
```

I've tried escaping the { and } but that doesn't seem to work either - what am I doing wrong?

Cheers

MH

Comment: Both answers below arebasically correct, I just wanted to notd your "ls" expression is not regexp, and not ls.   It is a combination of bash's BRACE and PATHNAME expansions.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering if there was a difference in the regex on the find and the expansion of parameters in the ls by the "same" expression. As I mentioned, I tried the regex answer by qor72 and it didn't return any results, but I'll try that in Linux tonight to see if it works there and it's cygwin that's being quirky

Comment: I found that I had to change qor72's expression on Linux to `find . -iregex '.*/\(EA\|FS\)_.*'` and MacOs to `find -E . -iregex '.*/(EA|FS)_.*'`  go figure :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need a regular expression instead of the usual name glob:

```
find . -iregex './\(EA\|FS\)_.*'
```

Remember with this syntax that you have to match the directory too. From your commands it looks like you're doing it all in one directory (no depth) so what I've provided will work. For more recursive searches you'd need a different regex.

Test run on Cygwin, Windows 7:

```
$ find . -iregex './\(RT\|ED\).*' | head
./ED-AT-CK01-A01.xml
./ED-AT-CK02-A01.xml
./ED-AT-CL01-A01.xml
./ED-AT-CL02-A01.xml
./ED-AT-CL03-A01.xml
./ED-AT-CL04-A01.xml
./ED-AT-IL001-A01.xml
./ED-AT-IL01-A01.xml
./ED-AT-IL02-A01.xml
./ED-AT-TB02-A01.xml
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work - unless there are any other suggestions I'll try it on my Linux system tonight, in case it's something odd with cygwin

Comment: @Mad I'm running it in Cygwin for testing. The syntax is painful, imo. Did I mess up your RE?

Comment: ahah, that's the puppy - thx. Am I correct in saying that in normal regexs you wouldn't have to put in all those escape characters?  I've done lots of bits with regexs before, even some rather complex ones, but I only ever need to use them sporadically so it could just me being OOP with them =8) (or maybe it's the cygwin being a bit weird, if a normal regex wouldn't need all those escape chars).

Comment: @Mad When you have to get RE chars to the RE engine the escaping is required. It's much more painful on the command line. It looks 'cleaner' in code, usually.

Comment: Yes, that works that way in pure Linux too - I'm more used to using it in compiled code where the escaping isn't required - don't think I've ever needed to do any serious regex work in the shell up to now.  This is the joy of using 8 or 9 different languages/shells/etc - remembering the syntactical idiosyncrasies of each one, lol/sob

Answer (score 4):

you can also do this

```
find . -type f \( -iname "ES*" -o -iname "FS_*" \)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for this simple example but I will want to do it in a single regex as the search criteria will get a lot more complex, but I was wondering what the difference was in the regex implementation (or if I'm doing it wrong) for this simple example, before I start getting more complex

Comment: @Mad Halfing, please look at the man page of `find` to see the requirements of using `iregex`. It searches for a whole path, not the file names.

Comment: I have looked at the man page - it's getting the regex to work - even finding EA, for example, anywhere in the filename doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, unfortunately I can't mark this as the answer as well as the other answer, so I've upvoted it for you.

Comment: @Mad Halfling: the patterns you're using are glob patterns, *not* regex patterns -- if you want to use then with with regex tools, you need to translate them (e.g. the glob pattern `*EA*` is equivalent to the regex `.*EA.*`).

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I twigged that and noted it in an earlier comment but there was still the fun of having to escape the chars in the shell command that was making me doubt whether my regex was right, or not.  As I said, I was having a bad-brain-day =8)